# What is the easiest method to move files into current directory in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

I was wondering if there was a cleaner method to move files into the current directory than this:

```
mv path/to/file ../current_directory
```

If I wanted to move a file to the directory above I could go:

```
mv file ..
```

Is there a way to represent the current directory?

Comment: Two dots (`..`) is directory above, one dot (`.`) is current DIR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current directory is `.`, so you can use:

```
mv path/to/file .
```

Answer (score 0):

"PWD" is the environment variable for current directory.
So, you can do :

```
mv path/to/file $PWD/
```

You can test this yourself, for example :

```
cd /tmp
touch test-file.txt
mkdir /tmp/test-dir
cd test-dir
echo $PWD
mv /tmp/test-file.txt $PWD/
ls -la $PWD/
```